# permission denied for ed25519 ssh key with custom name

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I'm in an Ubuntu server.

I've generated a new Ed25519 ssh key with a custom name and copied the generated public key to my Gitlab account. But when I try to clone my repository to the server. I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, I'm not facing this issue with the Ed25519 key that's generated with the default name `id_ed25519` is working fine.

What's causing this issue and is there a workaround?

Comment: This should be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Answer (score 2):

When you define custom key name, then you need to add it to ssh config, like so:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_private_key
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

Comment: This is what worked for me